# Reading text value from Qtablewidget and assign automatically to Qcombobox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have a `QTableWidget` and a `Qcombobox`. I want to get text values from every single cell in first column `1` and when ever a user inserts a new value, that would assign and set automatically to `Qcombobox`. What I mean by every single cell is to get available values, when a cell is empty then do nothing.

**Visualization:**

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(combo)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 2, self)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4', 'Name 5']
        for index, name in enumerate(names):
            self.table.setItem(index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(name))

class Layout(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Layout, self).__init__()
        self.comb = Widget()
        self.table = Window()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.comb)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Layout()
    window.setGeometry(600, 200, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am not sure about connection and slot solution will give a good choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this it is better to pass as a model so that it is automatically updated without the unnecessary use of signals. But since you want no empty elements to be displayed, use QSortFilterProxyModel with an [appropriate regex](https://www.regextester.com/98264):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 2)
        names = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4', 'Name 5']
        for index, name in enumerate(names):
            self.table.setItem(index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(name))

        proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        proxy.setSourceModel(self.table.model())
        proxy.setFilterRegExp(r"^(?!\s*$).+")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.setModel(proxy)
        self.comboBox.setModelColumn(0)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 200, 300, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```